# JQuery AutoComplete not working with ashx

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am working on JQuery AutoComplete on my ASP.NET page.  And, I am using ashx file to populate list.

But, the ashx looks like it's not firing.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

jQuery code

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%=txtBox.ClientID%>").autocomplete('MyList.ashx', { minChars: 1 });
});
```

.ashx code

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.yoursite.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
public class MyList: IHttpHandler
{ 
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        //Just to test
        context.Response.Write("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set MIME content-type for the ashx to return json data.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write("['Content1', 'Content2']");  //consider using JsonSerializer
```

Also, specify json as the data type for the source to autocomplete.

```
$("...").autocomplete('MyList.ashx', { dataType: "json" });
```